# MySql update with low cost CPU

Tags: mysql, sql-update, ranking

I am implementing a leader board in my application, I want to update it every few time.
For that I created two tables of leader boards, that each one looks like this:

```
user_id, score, rank
```

and this is my update query:

```
select score from leaderboard order by score for update;
select(@rankCounter := 0);
update leaderboard set rank = (select(@rankCounter := @rankCounter + 1)) order by score desc;
```

I am using my active table for queries and every few time I switch the active table.

The update is currently taking around 3 minutes (on my machine) to update 4M raws.
I wish to reduce the amount of CPU it takes, and I don't care that the update will take longer.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try adding an index `... ON leaderboard (score)`, to avoid a sort operation. I also recommend you remove the unnecessary SELECT from the UPDATE statement (but I don't know if that has any performance implications or not, but the SELECT keyword is not necessary in that context.

A sort operation is certainly going to use some CPU. It's not clear to me whether that SELECT inside the UPDATE statement is ignored by the optimizer, or whether the plan is somehow different with that (unnecessary?) SELECT in there.  (What is the purpose of including the SELECT keyword in that context?)

Also, it is not necessary to return the score value from every row to obtain locks on all the rows in the leaderboard table. The ORDER BY on that SELECT statement could also be consuming CPU cycles (if there is no index with `score` as the leading column. The unnecessary preparation of a 4M row resultset is also consuming CPU cycles.

It's not clear why it's necessary to obtain locks on all those rows in the table, with a SELECT ... FOR UPDATE, when the UPDATE statement itself will obtain the necessary locks.  (The SELECT ... FOR UPDATE statement will only obtain locks in the context of a BEGIN TRANSACTION, or if autocommit is disabled. (I'm assuming here that `leaderboard` is an InnoDB table.)

---

MySQL may be able to make use of an index to avoid a sort operation:

```
CREATE INDEX leaderboard_IX1 ON leaderboard (score) ;
```

And this should be sufficient to update the rank column:

```
SET @rankCounter := 0;
UPDATE leaderboard
  SET rank = @rankCounter := @rankCounter + 1
ORDER BY score DESC ;
```

Comment: Tnx this helped me to improve the performance a bit. But the question is how to reduce CPU, because the time almost didn't changed, and so it the CPU.